# WPF MVVM Prevent tab change

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am having a WPF Tab control with two tabs called "OFFLINE" & "ONLINE". When "ONLINE" tab click, I need to chek whether application is in online status or not.If (status ! = online) 
display error message and prevent displaying "ONLINE" (2nd) tab and go to "OFFLINE" tab.

**VIEW.XAML**

```
 <TabControl Name="dashboardTabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex,Mode=TwoWay}">
        <TabItem Header="Local Dashboard">
            <views:OfflineDashboard DataContext="{Binding OfflineDashboardViewModel}"/>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Online Dashboard">
            <views:OnlineDashboard DataContext="{Binding OnlineDashboardViewModel}"/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```

**VIEWMODEL**

```
       public int SelectedTabIndex
        {
            get
            {
                return this.selectedTabIndex;
            }

            set
            {
                if (value == 1 && !applicationData.IsApplicationOnline())
                {
                    this.SelectedTabIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.selectedTabIndex = value;
                }

                // TODO : According to the selected tab index , populate ONLINE/OFFLINE 
viewmodels

NotifyPropertyChange("SelectedTabIndex");
            }
        }
```

**Question** : Although i checked status and set tab to 0, it doesn't work.
always onclick of 2nd tab it will displayed ONLINE tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a solution for my problem:

**XAML**

```
<TabControl Name="dashboardTabControl"  Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <TabItem Header="Local Dashboard" IsSelected="{Binding IsOnline,Converter={StaticResource invertBoolConverter}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                    <views:OfflineDashboard DataContext="{Binding OfflineDashboardViewModel}"/>
                </TabItem>
                <TabItem Header="Online Dashboard" IsSelected="{Binding IsOnline}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
                    <views:OnlineDashboard DataContext="{Binding OnlineDashboardViewModel}"/>
                </TabItem>
```

Now I am using `IsSelected` property of TabItem, instead of `SelectedIndex`

**VIEWMODEL**

```
public bool IsOnline
        {
            get
            {
                return isOnline;
            }
            set
            {
                // When ONLINE tab click, check whether application is online,
                // if not, do not display ONLINE tab
                if (value && !applicationData.IsApplicationOnline())
                {
                    isOnline = false;
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    isOnline = value;
                }

                LoadTabContent();

                NotifyPropertyChange("IsOnline");
            }
        }
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this the other way around.

Have the ViewModel listen for network changes and expose a bool property Online.

Bind the Enabled property of the Tabpages to this bool.

That way you do not pollute the ViewModel with UI code.

Comment: yes I also suggested this to my team. since we are using Mediator we can get use of that for this problem. But disabling tab is not a business requirement.

Comment: You can also bind any other visual aspect to the Online property.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) in your `ViewModel`. After changing the `SelectedTabIndex` notify View that selected index of tab control has been changed via [PropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) event of `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

And in your XAML do

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```